# Reconstruct tree based on sum relation

Tags: tree, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering

Given a set of nodes with a name and a value

```
name   value
(A)       10
(B)       15                    
(C)        5
```

how can find a tree, assuming that the value of the parent is the sum of all children values.

```
           (B)     // 15 = 10 + 5
          /   \
        (A)   (C)
```

**Real world example:**

Imaging a file system. Each node is either a directory or a file. Each node has a value. In the case of a file the value equals its file size. For a directory the value is the sum of all children values.

Now we delete all relations between the nodes and the information whether it is a directory( node with child relations) or a file.

What possible approaches exist to reconstruct that tree?

Comment: Does the order of elements need to be preserved? As in, could we permute the weights you assigned to A, B, and C and then reorder the nodes when building the final tree?

Comment: No, the question is the same for C,B,A. But the identity of the node should be preserved.